# Correct Path for Git Remote Add from Amazon EC2 Instance to OSX Client Machine

Tags: git, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to do a `git remote add` **from** a repository that sits on a remote Amazon AMI back **to** a cloned copy of the SAME repository that is sitting on my local OSX machine.

I'm confused about what file path to use. I assume it's something like:

```
git remote add my_clone <OSX_User_Name>@<OSX_HOST_NAME>:<PATH_TO_CLONED_REPO>
```

I obviously know what my `<OSX_User_Name>` is, and I can figure out my `<PATH_TO_CLONED_REPO>`, but I have no idea how to determine a `<OSX_HOST_NAME>` that would actually work.

- Can I just put in my external IP address, followed by my machine's internal IP address? (Note that I'm working behind a router.)
- Is `ssh://` the correct protocol?
- Do I need to set up ssh access from the Amazon EC2 machine to the local OSX machine?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out, and it has very little to do with Git.

First, in OSX, you need to enable Remote Login, on the Sharing screen, which can be accessed via the System Preferences screen.

Next, if you're client machine is behind a router, set up forwarding of all ssh traffic (which is over port 22 by default) to the internal IP address associated with your client machine.

Lastly, execute the following command on the Amazon EC2 machine:

```
git remote add my_clone \
<OSX_User_Name>@<External_IP_Address>:<Path to Cloned Repo>
```

Comment: You might want to not use port 22.  If you keep it there, your security logs will be mildly entertaining.

Comment: While you found a solution, this seems basically backwards. If there is no 'central' bare repository (implied) why not either create one anywhere, so that both working copies can push/pull from it OR just push from your mac to the ami repo? What is the fundamental reason for wanting to do things "backwards"?